# Is there a way to access the functions from the calling module scope in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have two `.ps1` files.  One calls the other.  I want to pass a function name to the other, so that the other can call the functions defined in the one's file (dependency injection).  Seems to be that when calling another `.ps1` file, it has no view of the functions from the caller module scope though.

Reason for doing this is so that I can spawn off some powershell instances that contain the functions.  However, since these are separate instances, they will not have any access to the callers code, so I need to regenerate the functions and feed them into the new process by stating what functions I wish to export and convert those functions into a script string something like so:

```
Param(
   [string]$Command,
   [Array]$IncludeFunction = @()
)
Begin{
  $Command += "`r`n"
  Foreach ($functionName in $IncludeFunction)
  {
      $Command += "function $functionName() { ${function:$functionName} }`r`n"
  }
}
```

I've noticed that it is possible to get access to the variables of the calling module scope, so I'm wondering if this is possible for the functions as well.

Comment: Anything wron with simply dot-sourcing the other file? `. 'C:\path\to\other.ps1'`

Comment: Yeah, just discovered that, but turns out that it wasn't needed.  Seems that `${function:$functionName}` doesn't work.  I have to use `(get-command $functionName).Definition` instead. o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty way for including functions in a script is to write the functions to a second script and [dot-source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx) that in the script where you want to use the function(s):

```
# script1.ps1

. 'C:\path\to\script2.ps1'

SomeFunctionFromScript2 -Foo 'bar'
```

If you want to provide a function library for more than one script it's better to wrap the functions inta a [script module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
# library.psm1

function FunctionA {
  ...
}

function FunctionB {
  ...
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *
```

Then you can distribute the library and people can import it like any other module:

```
# script1.ps1

Import-Module library

FunctionA ...
```

Comment: Is dot-source implied when piping into a `.ps1` file?

Comment: @Adrian No. That's something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that they weren't available, it was due to the fact that `${function:$functionName}` doesn't work.  I have to use `(get-command $functionName).Definition` instead.  Not sure why this is so.